# How can i get the same result in Progress 4gl?

Tags: sql, progress-4gl

How can i implement  query like this in Progress 4GL

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM tbl1 
   WHERE field1 IN (SELECT Field1 FROM tbl2).
```

I have just 2 ideals one with temp-table and second with CAN-DO() function... but CAN-DO() function work with string, so i have to convert this field to string.. but this is bad idea...
I am newbie in Progress.

Comment: CAN-DO() is a security function.  It was perverted for use as a string matching function in the dark ages prior to the 4GL supporting INDEX() and LOOKUP().  Unfortunately a lot of old code that uses it has been freely copied by people who do not understand the very significant downsides to using CAN-DO in WHERE clauses.  It was reasonable for security in 1984 but today it is a very poor way to implement security.  If you have colleagues suggesting its use they are acting out of ancient bad habits. To sum it up:  if you find yourself typing CAN-DO you are almost certainly making a big mistake.

Comment: Thank you Tom for helping ! Realy amazing description about CAN-DO() function. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
FOR EACH tbl2 FIELDS(tbl2.Field1)
    NO-LOCK,
    EACH tbl1 FIELDS(tbl1.field1 tbl1.field2)
    WHERE tbl1.field1= tbl2.Field1
    NO-LOCK:
 ...
END.
```

`FIELDS` instruction is optional.

If the second select is more complicated, you can also do nested FOR EACH:

```
FOR EACH tbl2
    WHERE ...
    NO-LOCK:
    ...
    FOR EACH tbl1
        WHERE tbl1.field1= tbl2.Field1
        NO-LOCK:
     ...
    END.
END.
```